# How to print a table made in JavaScript with the data filtered by checkboxes, without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, html-table

I have a table displaying some data, made only in JavaScript. Now, I put some checkboxes in order to filter the the data and show the table with the matches selected before. Without using jQuery, and without "hidding" the rows unselected, I need to create a new table every time a checkbox is selected.

This is the HTML

```
<div>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sParty" value="democrat"> Democrat
    <input type="checkbox" name="sParty" value="republican"> Republican
    <input type="checkbox" name="sParty" value="independent" checked> Independent
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="row" id="tablerow">
  <div class="col">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm" id="sendata">
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this the JS (I started by getting the NodeList from the checkboxes)

```
var memberArr=data.results[0].members;  //BRINGS DATA FROM JSON FILA
var newArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < memberArr.length; i++) {
  var obj = new Object; 
  obj.fullName= memberArr[i].first_name + " " + (memberArr[i].middle_name || " ") +  " " + memberArr[i].last_name;                  
  obj.party = memberArr[i].party;
  obj.state = memberArr[i].state;
  obj.seniority = memberArr[i].seniority;
  obj.votes_with_party_pct=memberArr[i].votes_with_party_pct + "  %" ;
  obj.nameLink=memberArr[i].url;
  newArr.push(obj);                             
} //newArr is the array with all members(objects)

var checkedBoxes = 
      document.querySelectorAll('input[name=mycheckboxes]:checked');  //GET 
VALUE OF CHECKED CHECKBOXES

var headersSenate={
  HfullName:"Full Name",
  Party:"Party Affilication",
  State:"State",
  Senior:"Seniority",
  Votes:"Votes w/Party (pct)",
}

var datos="<tr><th>" + headersSenate.HfullName + "</th><th>"+ headersSenate.Party + "</th><th>" + headersSenate.State+ "</th><th>"
            +headersSenate.Senior+ "</th><th>"+headersSenate.Votes+"</th>";

for(var i=0; i<newArr.length; i++){
  datos+="<tr><td><a target='_blank' href=" + newArr[i].nameLink + ">"+ newArr[i].fullName + "</a></td><td>" + newArr[i].party
  + "</td><td>" + newArr[i].state + "</td><td>" + newArr[i].seniority + "</td><td>" + newArr[i].votes_with_party_pct + "</td>";
}
document.getElementById("sendata").innerHTML= datos;
```

Comment: It is very hard to figure it out without some example data, because we don't know how your table is structured. It would be nice if you could edit your question accordingly.

Comment: for example, newArr is the array which contains all the data, each congress member as an object as: newArr=[  {first_name: "Carl", state: "IO", party: "D"} {first_name: "Tom", state: "CA", party: "R}.....] and I need to filter between parties